# Spring boot shows Whitelabel Error Page, else bock is not excecuting in mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring boot project with Data JPA using MySQL. I have a mapping for login in my application and if I enter correct credentials it works perfectly but in case of of wrong credentials it shows whitelabel error. I tried wasting my hours on this but nothing helped. Please suggest what can I do to fix this. Below is the configuration of my project.

```
 Controller class

 @RequestMapping("/signin")
public String signIn(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String pass)
{
    User user=repo.findByemail(email);


    if(user.getPassword().equals(pass))
    {
        return "login";
    }
    else
    {
       /*Else block never executes. I tied printing something on console nothing works. */
        return "login";
    }

}
```

---

My Repo

```
  @Repository
  public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

      User findByemail(String email);
   }
```

Please let me know if you need more explanation about any code.

Comment: try to use null check `if(user != null && user.getPassword().equals(pass))`

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi is right

Comment: Thank you @alex but I have already did all that stuff nothing seemed to work. With correct credentials it executes if block but when I try to give wrong credentials it never executes else block.

The only problem is with this project is, In case of wrong it gives whitelable error instead of executing defined code for wrong credentials.

Comment: Maybe you should add password null check `if(user != null && user.getPassword() != null && user.getPassword().equals(pass))`

Comment: Thank you!! @alexvaluiskyi

It's working, What could be the reason of this issue

Answer (score 0):

You must check if user is not null before access any property

```
User user=repo.findByemail(email);


if(user != null && user.getPassword().equals(pass))
{
    // Do login success stuff
}
else
{
    return "login";
}
```

You will get a NullPointerException when execute user.getPassword() if the user don't exists.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it answers all :)